# listView and row view creation problems flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, compiler-errors

I have my listView that works correctly without the Row code, but I need to place a textfield and a button under the last element of the ListView. both at the same height. that's why I thought about using Row. but if I try to write it under my listView and start the app, I don't see anything, not even the listView. as an error it is only reported to me:

> > The relevant error-causing widget was:
> > ListView file:///Users/apple/Desktop/Work%202021/toduba-merchant/lib/tabs/home_tab.dart:95:22
> > When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> > #0      RenderViewportBase._paintContents (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:649:25)
> > #1      RenderViewportBase.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:641:7)
> > #2      RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
> > #3      PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:140:11)
> > #4      PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
> > ...
> > The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#ba090
> > ...  needs compositing
> > ...  parentData:  (can use size)
> > ...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=375.0, h=474.9)
> > ...  layer: OffsetLayer#32030 DETACHED
> > ...    engine layer: Null#007db
> > ...    offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
> > ...  size: Size(375.0, 474.9)
> > ...  axisDirection: down
> > ...  crossAxisDirection: right
> > ...  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#d8a7b(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: 474.9, ScrollableState, BouncingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#f75ff, ScrollDirection.idle)
> > ...  anchor: 0.0
> > RenderObject: RenderViewport#ba090
> > needs compositing
> > parentData:  (can use size)
> > constraints: BoxConstraints(w=375.0, h=474.9)
> > layer: OffsetLayer#32030 DETACHED
> > engine layer: Null#007db
> > offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
> > size: Size(375.0, 474.9)
> > axisDirection: down
> > crossAxisDirection: right
> > offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#d8a7b(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: 474.9, ScrollableState, BouncingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#f75ff, ScrollDirection.idle)
> > anchor: 0.0
> > ...  center child: RenderSliverPadding#7222a relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
> > ...    needs compositing
> > ...    parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
> > ...    constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.down, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 474.9, crossAxisExtent: 375.0, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.right, viewportMainAxisExtent: 474.9, remainingCacheExtent: 724.9, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
> > ...    geometry: null
> > ...    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0)
> > ...    textDirection: ltr
> > ...    child: RenderSliverList#9d74e relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
> > ...      needs compositing
> > ...      parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
> > ...      constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.down, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 454.9, crossAxisExtent: 335.0, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.right, viewportMainAxisExtent: 474.9, remainingCacheExtent: 704.9, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
> > ...      geometry: null
> > ...      currently live children: 0 to 3
> > ...      child with index 0: RenderIndexedSemantics#3b488 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
> > ...        needs compositing
> > ...        parentData: index=0; layoutOffset=0.0 (can use size)
> > ...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=335.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> > ...        semantic boundary
> > ...        size: Size(335.0, 29.0)
> > ...        index: 0
> > ...        child: RenderRepaintBoundary#8cd41 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
> > ...          needs compositing
> > ...          parentData:  (can use size)
> > ...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=335.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> > ...          size: Size(335.0, 29.0)
> > ...          usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
> > ...      child with index 1: RenderIndexedSemantics#c3e1f relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
> > ...        needs compositing
> > ...        parentData: index=1; layoutOffset=29.0 (can use size)
> > ...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=335.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> > ...        semantic boundary
> > ...        size: Size(335.0, 260.0)
> > ...        index: 1
> > ...        child: RenderRepaintBoundary#16c99 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
> > ...          needs compositing
> > ...          parentData:  (can use size)
> > ...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=335.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> > ...          size: Size(335.0, 260.0)
> > ...          usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
> > ...      child with index 2: RenderIndexedSemantics#967b1 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
> > ...        needs compositing
> > ...        parentData: index=2; layoutOffset=289.0 (can use size)
> > ...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=335.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> > ...        semantic boundary
> > ...        size: Size(335.0, 22.0)
> > ...        index: 2
> > ...        child: RenderRepaintBoundary#348b5 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
> > ...          needs compositing
> > ...          parentData:  (can use size)
> > ...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=335.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> > ...          size: Size(335.0, 22.0)
> > ...          usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
> > ...      child with index 3: RenderIndexedSemantics#047b6 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
> > ...        needs compositing
> > ...        parentData: index=3; layoutOffset=311.0 (can use size)
> > ...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=335.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> > ...        semantic boundary
> > ...        size: MISSING
> > ...        index: 3
> > ...        child: RenderRepaintBoundary#af13c relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
> > ...          needs compositing
> > ...          parentData:  (can use size)
> > ...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=335.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> > ...          size: MISSING
> > ...          usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)

```
return Container(
          color: appColors.primaryColor,
          child: ListView(
            primary: false,
                  children: [
                    // TITOLO
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                        child: Text(
                                localization.showQR,
                                style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                                  color: appColors.green,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                                child: qrCodeHolder
                            ),
                        ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                              child: AutoSizeText(
                                localization.home_subLabel,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                                  color: appColors.green,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    Positioned(
                      //top: size.height * .02,
                      //right: size.width * .02,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                            TextField(
                              inputFormatters: [
                                new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(7),
                              ],
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: Colors.white,
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Image.asset("assets/images/send.png"),
                            onPressed: () => showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => PaymentDialog()),
                          ),
                          Text("dfjbsdifbsdf"),
                        ]
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            ),
          );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your TextField in an Expanded widget or a container with limited width.
This is because the Row assumes it can take maximum width, and the TextField and TextFormField widget by default try to take the maximum width possible.

By putting them inside each other, you'll get the error you are having.

Use this for the `TextField`, inside a row, it must be wrapped in `Expanded` or `Flexible`.

```
Row(
 children: [
  Expanded(
   child: TextField () 
  )
])
```

Comment: also Textfield or all Row in a Expanded ?

Comment: `Row( children: [ Expanded( child: TextField () )])`

Just for the `TextField`, inside a row, it must be wrapped in `Expanded` or `Flexible`.

Comment: perfect it worked .. the text in an expander. now how can I detach the row from the listview a bit?

Comment: perfect it worked .. the text in an expander. now how can I detach the row from the listview a bit?

Comment: Kindly mark it as  a solution to your question and upvote if it was helpful. For your second question, please open a different post, to keep things organized and so future users can benefit from your problem. It's hard to find answers inside the comment section.

Comment: you're right, I'll open it right away. thanks for here :)